# Blender Cycles Baking And Small issue with textures

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, baking

I have 2 problems i want help with.
1.I my model textures appears *broken(as it shown on the picture) on glsl view in texture mode and in material mode with nodes or normal texturing.That is not happening on blender 2.8.[image]
2.I Want to bake texture and the outpout to be exactly as i see it on cycles render material view.Without shadows or lighting.I tried diffuse baking but the texture is ready dark.Thanks in advantage.Please help me on that.

Comment: About the baking, have you tried to plug the texture color directly to the surface material output (with no shader)?

Comment: thanks for the aswer i will try it

Comment: If you're just interested in the color without any shading at all, you can deactivate *Direct* and *Indirect* beneath the *Bake Type*.

Comment: Hello and thanks again for the help.I want to bake on a texture exaclty what i see on the viewport not on the render.That because i cannot find a way to light the scene so the texture of my character will be "clean" but shaded on render.Without shadows or reflections.